# Flash Animations Skipping, Uncalled Audio Playing

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe, flash-cs5

I am totally baffled at the moment.

I have a Flash CS5/AS3 project, a large Flash game, that uses a LOT of animations. I've divided these up into a MovieClip on a Scene, with corresponding actionscripts and events, for the "exploring screens", and another MovieClip on a Scene for one of the challenges, and another such set for another challenge.

This method allows me to put only the animations that section needs into the corresponding MovieClip, and link the events of the scene to its MovieClip.

However, I obviously have to link these. I use the following to do it:

```
stop();
thismovieclip.stop();
gotoAndPlay(1, "THAT_SCENE");
```

The next movieclip starts automatically when the next scene shows up.

This works well in theory. But, though the correct Scene shows up, that scene's movieclip is skipping erratically (as opposed to playing smoothly), and its audiocues are playing, along with the audiocues from another movieclip that I neither called nor have on this Scene. (Mind you, that movieclip hadn't even RUN yet.)

What is going on? How do I fix it? I KNOW it is possible, but how do I do it?

EDIT: I did find a workaround that eliminates the use of scenes altogether, however if anyone has any useful information or possible solutions, they are encouraged to answer!

Comment: Scene errors are somewhat tricky to diagnose without seeing the full code.  Scenes are added together into one timeline on production of the SWF, so it is easy to imagine that you have an error somewhere that prevents your Actionscript from being processed correctly, and it just continues on to the next scene/frame.  If you would like me to look at the FLA, you can email it to my junk email at testdee@yahoo.com.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the offer, but since this contains some highly sensitive propitiatory code, I'm not licensed to transfer the .fla to anyone outside of the company. I found a work around, but I'm going to let this sit for a few more days before I post.

Comment: np.  However, you really need to provide more info in the question.  You have not provided any (seemingly) relevant info.  Please edit your question and note what is in your comment, so no one else tries to answer this.

Comment: There's really not much more that can BE provided. The relevant code is printed, and I've gone through my code with a fine toothed comb several dozen times...if anyone else has helpful info, they're welcome to post it. Otherwise, in a few days, I'll post my workaround.

Comment: I just mean to add a note stating that you are working on another solution . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a glitch in Scenes, such that playing a previous scene also plays all scenes between the current and the target scene. Hopefully this will be addressed in CS6.

Meanwhile, if anyone is needing to navigate between scenes, I recommend using MovieClips intead on ONE scene, and hiding and showing those to achieve the same thing.